# Replacing range of values in R

Tags: r, if-statement, replace, range

I'm trying to replace a range of values, 1 to 14, with a new range of values, 0 to 13, using the `ifelse` function in R. My code is getting lengthy:

```
new_var <- with(data, ifelse(var==1, 0, ifelse(var==2, 1, ifelse(var==3, 2, ... ifelse(var==14, 13, NA))))
```

Is there a way to specify ranges using `ifelse`? I tried this but it didn't work:

```
new_var <- with(data, ifelse(var==c(1:14), c(0:13), NA))
```

Comment: data$new_var = data$var - 1 ?

Comment: Perfect--a much simpler approach!

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 data %>%
      mutate(new_var = var -1)
```